# looping through recordset in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

Im trying to get a recordset loop code working, i have my bellow code which keeps inputing a zero. My second piece of code is identical code but displaying the qty in a message box. The number it is displaying is the number i want to input into my field. I just cant seem to get it to put the number in the field !Qty?

```
Dim Val As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Forms!frmReceive!sfrmReceiveDetailEntry.Form.RecordsetClone
With rs
Do While Not rs.EOF

rs.Edit
Val = Nz(DLookup("[RemainingQty]", "tblQtySoFarTEMP", "[OrderDetailPK]= " & rs!    [OrderDetailFK]))
rs!Qty = Val
rs.Update

rs.MoveNext
Loop
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Displaying value in message box

```
Dim val As Integer

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Forms!frmReceive!sfrmReceiveDetailEntry.Form.RecordsetClone
With rs
Do While Not rs.EOF
val = Nz(DLookup("[RemainingQty]", "tblQtySoFarTEMP", "[OrderDetailPK]= " & rs! [OrderDetailFK]))

MsgBox val

rs.MoveNext
Loop
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: I only see that you have a with rs statement and then still use rs to reference the table. Should not be a problem, but when you get errors you cant locate, always try to avoid with statements. - And then try moving the Edit down one line/moving the val= statement before the edit...

Comment: I agree with @Johanness, move the `rs.Edit` below your `Val=` code. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out in the end, this is my working code!

```
'If YES then run the following code
AreYouSure = MsgBox("You are about to Receive All of Order" & txtOrderNumber.Value & " ,   Are you Sure?, The whole order and it's Quantities will be updated?", vbYesNo, "Receive  All?")
If (AreYouSure = vbYes) Then
'disable warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'Create recordsetclone of subform
'loop recordset and lookup remaining qty to receive all
Set rs = Forms!frmReceive!sfrmReceiveDetailEntry.Form.RecordsetClone
   With rs
      Do While Not rs.EOF

       rs.Edit
       rs("Qty") = Nz(DLookup("[RemainingQty]", "tblQtySoFarTEMP", "[OrderDetailPK]= " & rs![OrderDetailFK]))
       rs.Update
       rs.MoveNext
      Loop
  End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Still. Make yure you are not using the With clause and the recordset-variable (rs) in the same place. if you have with rs you dont need rs.edit but .edit is enough. Being clear about things like that will prevent you from hours of debugging frustration later.